# Json parsing to fetch nearest gas stations in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am parsing a `json` ,which is a `json object` to start with.it has an array `html_attributions[]` and another array `results[]`

Now as i create the `json` string from the `URL`, I can see my json string is coming. But in creating the json object from the json string I am having `illegalArugumentException` , `illegal character in scheme at index 0`.

My objective is to find the locations from the json and mark that in my google mapview.

here is my asynctask class..

```
class LocationJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();String url = jParser.getJSONStringFromUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=37.78583400,-122.40641700&radius=1500&types=gas_station&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyBIwW4m6xINOhM_j7hckMAbD3oks_fkLFc");

            //main json abject
            jsonObject = jParser.getJSONObject(url);


            //get to the results array:
            try {
                JSONArray htmlArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("html_attributions");
                JSONArray resultsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

                //get to the geometry objects
                for (int i = 0; i < resultsArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject geometry = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);


                    //get to the location object
                    JSONObject location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");

                    //get to the lat string
                    double lati = Double.parseDouble(location.getString("Lat"));
                    double longi = Double.parseDouble(location.getString("lng"));

                    //create a latlong object
                    place = new LatLng(lati,longi);

                      /*//set the map
                    Marker melbourne = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(place)

                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));


                    //set the camera
                    cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place, 10);
                        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);*/


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            //set the map
        Marker melbourne = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(place)

        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));


        //set the camera
         CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place, 10);

         map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

        }

    }
```

//here is my jsonparser class    public class JSONParser {

```
static InputStream is = null;

    static JSONObject jObj = null;

    static String json = "";

    static JSONArray jArray = null;



    // constructor

    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public String getJSONStringFromUrl(String url) {


        // Making HTTP request

        try {

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()

                    .permitAll().build();


            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            // defaultHttpClient

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);


            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            is = httpEntity.getContent();


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }    

        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(

                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }

            is.close();

            json = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());

        }  


        // return JSON String

        return json;


    }    

    public JSONObject getJSONObject(String url) {

        // try parse the string to a JSON object


        getJSONStringFromUrl(url);

        try {

            jObj = new JSONObject(json);

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            Log.e("JSON Parser Object",

                    "Error parsing jsonObject " + e.toString());

        }   


        // return JSON String

        return jObj;

    }   

    public JSONArray getJSONArray(String url) {

        // try parse the string to a JSON array


        getJSONStringFromUrl(url);

        try {

            jArray = new JSONArray(json);

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            Log.e("JSON Parser Array",

                    "Error parsing jsonArray " + e.toString());

        }    

        // return JSON String

        return jArray;   

    }
}
```

here is the json data

```
{
  "html_attributions": [

  ],
  "results": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 37.7774450,
          "lng": -122.4048230
        }
      },
      "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/gas_station-71.png",
      "id": "8e31a915604dd3597225152bfd3ec6f9bfa39395",
      "name": "Chevron",
      "photos": [
        {
          "height": 640,
          "html_attributions": [
            "From a Google User"
          ],
          "photo_reference": "CnRiAAAADAcSOQpR_AW86egDLCWLpuEf00zuXUVFbcxh5-zCY5OzIUtJx764rn2mLnWTMA0xsz3AG7e0ZbU3n_GTJcOI0O15N1Va34GhUMiXirAw6h0DUETlElRwzvNjv1sQoFdimUYCOg-Us4ow9hoeq4cx-RIQSqRYof89YFdoVKRokkHN6RoUT4nJ4eofBuD1pJgwVeIKiaOlVo4",
          "width": 480
        }
      ],
      "rating": 3.20,
      "reference": "CnRkAAAAQ8TbCf9PqmO-_2-vgbFdrKE9j5PIknybR43IdTMziGYAuj5yOW3PcCCfLMgaeEM0ulLWU2WI3-YX14d1bza8tDYAEQlsP4JMTRT1RAeCm_CzhhhcZaB6UZ2Q2_f33iNHxMvoPumNwef6OXXmPQkusxIQ80SUv_R8odDO1dds5ovKZBoURT26TM5W2qKebWGQxfPE0SRgLwQ",
      "types": [
        "car_repair",
        "gas_station",
        "establishment"
      ],
      "vicinity": "1000 Harrison Street, San Francisco"
    },

      ],

  "status": "OK"
}
```

Comment: use GSON to parse your json response.

Answer (score 1):

-Mahaveer Muttha is right.

Here checkout the Gson Guide

[Gson User Guide with tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

Answer (score 0):

How I'm parsing google places response to get names of locations:

```
//data is a String with your JSON
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray googlePlaces = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
String[] googlePlacesNames = getStringFromJsonArray(googlePlaces, "name");

private String[] getStringFromJsonArray(JSONArray source, String fieldName){
        String result[] = new String[source.length()];
        JSONObject json;
        try {
            for (int i=0; i<source.length();i++) {
                json = source.getJSONObject(i);
                result[i]=json.getString("name");
                Log.d("Places", "Next museum: " + result[i]);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  result;
    }
```

Advice to use GSON for parsing JSON objects is worth attention. By the way, Jackson library could be even better solution for json parsing: http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Comment: which class is providing me the JSONObject?

Comment: tell me the library for all the methods here. like "getJsonArray()","getStringFromJsonArray() ",getJsonObject() etc.

Comment: import org.json.JSONObject; getStringFromJsonArray() method is in code snippet

Answer (score 0):

This way of passing JSON String to Object is more prone to errors. My advice is to use the [Spring RestTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) There you will not have to manipulate the JSON Objects manually. The RestTemplate will get everything done for you when it comes to serializing and desalinizing the JSON String. You will only need to have an entity class which you will have all the fields related to the Gas Stations. You can request a List of Gas Stations even from the RestTemplate. It's a matter of dealing with Java Objects and not this burden of JSON String manipulating manually.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
List<GasStation> stations = (List) restTemplate.getForObject(yourURL, List.class);
```

The above code will get you a list of Gas Stations to your code.